# Flutter appbundle, doesn't upload on play console

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to upload my appbundle in play console but it keeps uploading by hours and doesn't do absolutely nothing, it doesn't give a error or something else, only keeps uploading

I've already signed my app and generated my flutter build appbundle --release. When i generate flutter build apk --release the app works perfect. What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your network connection or try it later!